# javascript addEventListener multiple classes

Tags: javascript, css, addeventlistener

I'm trying to add the same event to 2 differnt classes of elements.
I've successfully used the code below for one class:

```
    var MyClass = document.getElementsByClassName("BtnOptList");
    for (var ii = 0; ii < MyClass.length; ii++) {
        MyClass[ii].addEventListener('click', myFunction, false);
    }
```

Then I've tryed using a loop to add event to 2 classes but the code has no effects

```
var Classes = array["BtnOptGroup", "BtnOptList"];
for (var i=0; i<Classes.length; i++){
    var MyClass = document.getElementsByClassName(Classes[i]);
    for (var ii = 0; ii < MyClass.length; ii++) {
        MyClass[ii].addEventListener('click', myFunction, false);
    }
}
```

What's wrong in the 2nd code?

Comment: check your console

Comment: `array["BtnOptGroup", "BtnOptList"]` should be `["BtnOptGroup", "BtnOptList"]`

Comment: `array["BtnOptGroup", "BtnOptList"]` => `["BtnOptGroup", "BtnOptList"]`

Comment: @PranavCBalan do you mean  the code is correct?

Comment: He means working without the console to see errors is a bad idea.

Comment: If you would look at the console, you would not have come here to ask this question.

Comment: @genespos : yes it is..... but you can use the first loop itself, using `queryySelectorAll` method :  `var MyClass = document.querySelectorAll(".BtnOptGroup,.BtnOptList");
    for (var ii = 0; ii < MyClass.length; ii++) {
        MyClass[ii].addEventListener('click', myFunction, false);
    }`

Comment: @trincot I've learnt that javascript errors are in the console just reading your comment. Sorry for the bad question but I'm learning by myself

Comment: @PranavCBalan Thanks, I've tried a similar solution but with wrong function.Now I know how to ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You has errors in next code:
You use  `array["BtnOptGroup", "BtnOptList"]` , `should be ["BtnOptGroup", "BtnOptList"]` and I recommend  to use `document.querySelection()` instead of `document.getElementsByClassName()` , becouse it is faster.